# Как убрать отсупы между элементами в LinearLayout?

Tags: android

Вот такие огромные отсупы у меня между элементами, как мх уменьшить? Есть какой-нибудь атрибут?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разметка:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:contentDescription="Your description here."
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
    tools:context=".KursActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvKurs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Ваш ребенок научится:"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Мыслить алгоритмически"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/logic"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/mir"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/projects"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/brain" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/logic" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView8"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/idea" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Покажите как у вас разметка выглядит в xml представлении

Comment: добавила я ее, короктий текст впихнула сразу, а длинный через string

Comment: Вам надо либо отступы убрать у текстовых полей (android:layout_marginTop="64dp) и/или высоту оных в wrap_content установить

Comment: я это же поставила, чтобы они по центру встали

Comment: По центру относительно чего? Если по вертикали - то это будет работать только на ряде девайсов со стандартными настройками ОС. На остальных всё будет иначе выглядеть

Comment: спасибо, разобралась)) получилось

Comment: В ыашем случае совершенно лишний корневой контенер ConstraintLayout, он никак не используется, но отнимает ресурсы на свою обработку. Сделайте корневым контейнером ScrollView, как здесь: https://javadevblog.com/primer-ispol-zovaniya-scrollview-v-android.html

Answer (score 1):

Убрать у каждого элемента параметр  `android:layout_marginTop`, который как раз и задаёт отступ от верхнего элемента.